# CodeIgniter - Insert a new row in db with a boolean value

Tags: codeigniter

When CodeIgniter is inserting a row into a DB, it doesn't encode PHP booleans into a form MySQL needs.

For example:

```
$new_record = array(
 "name" => "Don",
 "is_awesome" => true
);
```

This will enter into MySQL as this:

```
name (varchar)   is_awesome (tinyint)
Don              0
```

Anyone know a good way to deal with this? I've been writing `(is_awesome == true) ? 1 : 0;` then setting the array value, but that sucks.

Answer (score 1):

you can't add `true` or `false` to a `TINYINT` in mysql. you should do `1` or `0` like this

```
$new_record = array(
"name" => "Don",
"is_awesome" => 1 //1 means it's true
);
$query = $this->db->insert('table_name', $new_record);
```

then just when you fetch it consider `0` as `false` and `1` as `true`

**Update:**
you can create a function called `tinyint_decode` like this:

```
public function tinyint_decode($result = array(), $decode_set = array())
{
 //$result is what you got from database after selecting
 //$decode_set is what you would like to replace 0 and 1 for
 //$decode_set can be like array(0=>'active', 1=>'inactive')
 //after fetching the array
 $result->is_awesome = ($result->is_awesome == 1 ? $decode_set[1] : $decode_set[0]);
return true;// or anything else

}
```

this way you can interpret `0` and `1` by anything you like whether it's true and false, active and inactive, or anything else just by passing `$decode_set` array.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but this doesn't answer my question about how to skip the step of encoding it as 1 or 0 from "true" and "false"

Comment: it's updated. take a look at it. but don't forget to fetch the results using foreach or whatever else before dealing with it or you will get an error of using stdClass in a wrong way.

Comment: @DonnyP - haven't heard back from you!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have boolean values. What I usually do is:

```
1) Have a field of length char(1) and say 'Y' or 'N'

OR

2) Have a numeric field and say '1' or '0'
```

The one method to encode you mentioned is the only way to do it. If it's an extra step, I would just get rid of boolean in the PHP code itself and make it a '1-0' or 'Y-N'

Comment: Having a 1 character mysql column with "Y" or "N" is a terrible idea. Anytime you return that row, and check in most languages if it's true or false, you're going to get true since the string exists.

Comment: Also looks like MySQL does have a bool type: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

maybe i should be using that

Comment: Yup you're right about the 1 Character thingy. I usually do 1 and 0.